# How can I communicate between libGDXand the Android Studio Java files?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

The reason I'm asking is because I wanted to create a game and I know I could use Scene2D to create the UI but as far as menus go I wanted to use the tools in android studio to at least create a menu that would lead to the game screen.

They say you should try to do everything in libgdx but how would I go on about trying to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the menu in one `Activity`, and let that `Activity` be a "*normal*" Android activity, then have that `Activity` launch the **libGDX** game `Activity`. That sort of approach would allow you to use Android layouts for the menu but **libGDX** for the actual game.

Comment: I created a button with an onClick method to take me to the libgdx java file with Intents but when i clicked the button the app crashes. Do you have a method that could help me?